# How do I use a Reserved IP address with Virtual Machines for ubuntu

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, azure

How do I use a Reserved IP address with Virtual Machines  for ubuntu?

So far I'm using the following syntax.But I couldn't make it.

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name "ubuntu" -InstanceSize Small -ImageName "Ubuntu*"| Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -ubuntu -AdminUsername "ubuntu" -Password "dangerrrrs09"| New-AzureVM -ServiceName "newubuntu" -ReservedIPName "MyReservedIP" -Location "South Central US"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it. 
`New-AzureVMConfig -Name "ubuntutest" -InstanceSize "Basic_A0" –ImageName "ubuntutestimage-20150611-670899" | New-AzureVM -ServiceName "ubuntutestimage" –ReservedIPName " demoreservedip` " -Location "West US” 
For more information
http://prmdbaora.blogspot.in/2015/06/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none.html?showComment=1442913898229#c8981497488772548579

Answer (score 0):

You need to [either](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/) 1) create the reserved IP address before you use it in New-AzureVM or 2) convert an existing VIP into a reserved IP address.

The syntax above for New-AzureVM looks correct, but the specification of -ImageName is incorrect in New-AzureVMConfig. You might look at this blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud_solution_architect/archive/2015/04/01/finding-the-most-recent-windows-server-2012-r2-template-with-powershell.aspx) for an idea of how to get the most recent image - the post is actually about Windows but it can trivially be changed to Ubuntu.

Comment: I used the syntax to get the image name                                                      ( Get-AzureVMImage | where-object { $_.Label -like "Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS*" } )   Here is the image name b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-12_04_3-LTS-amd64-
 server-20131205-en-us-30GB

Comment: Included the image name and tried , New-AzureVMConfig -Name "ubuntu" -InstanceSize Small -ImageName "b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-12_04_3-LTS-amd64-
 server-20131205-en-us-30GB
"| Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -ubuntu -AdminUsername "ubuntu" -Password "dangerrrrs09"| New-AzureVM -ServiceName "newubuntu" -ReservedIPName "MyReservedIP" -Location "South Central US"

Comment: Output:     Add-AzureProvisioningConfig : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ubuntu'.
At line:1 char:182
+ ... isioningConfig -ubuntu -AdminUsername "ubuntu" -Password "dangerrrrs09"| New-Azu ...
+                    ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-AzureProvisioningConfig], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.AddAzurePr
   ovisioningConfigCommand

Comment: Use -Linux NOT -Ubuntu for Add-AzureProvisioningConfig. Also use a different password since you have leaked your password in the comments

Comment: I have changed the ubuntu to linux still the same.FYI I'm using different password only.Here I'm posting something different.

Comment: This is how I fixed it.  New-AzureVMConfig -Name "ubuntutest" -InstanceSize "Basic_A0" –ImageName "ubuntutestimage-20150611-670899" | New-AzureVM -ServiceName "ubuntutestimage" –ReservedIPName " demoreservedip " -Location "West US”  For more information http://prmdbaora.blogspot.in/2015/06/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none.html